# Get the list of files from selected folders having sizes >100MB with their paths objective c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, size, nsfilemanager

I want to get the list of all files with their paths & sizes for my mac system.

From that, I want to filter only those files which have file size above 100 MB.

I got the size of my system using the below code.

```
NSError *error;

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [fileManager attributesOfFileSystemForPath:@"/" error:&error];
```

Now I want to get the list of files with their paths and sizes.

[image]

I searched a lot but those couldn't meet to my requirements.

Pleas help me on this.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: `enumeratorAtURL:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:errorHandler:` maybe?

Comment: @CRD: How can I implement it???

Comment: In the documentation for `enumeratorAtURL:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:errorHandler:` there is sample code which walks a tree collecting all the paths while ignoring certain folders. You can use this as a basis to walk the tree and collect all the sizes. If you get stuck ask another question and include your code, someone will probably be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my solution with the following scenario.

Thanks [CRD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/568283/crd) for giving me the idea.

First, I took a path of a folder. Then for getting subfolders only, I used `NSDirectoryEnumerator` and then I used the code to find the size of file.

Once I got the size of the file, then I checked the file size and added to my array.

So it worked.

```
NSString *Path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Users/%@/",NSUserName()];

NSDirectoryEnumerator *de = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath:Path];

NSString *file;
NSMutableArray *arrList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

 while ((file = [de nextObject]))
 NSLog(@"file %@",file);

 Path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Users/%@/",NSUserName()];

 Path = [Path stringByAppendingString:file];
 NSLog(@"path %@",Path);
NSError *attributesError = nil;

 NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:Path error:&attributesError];

 NSNumber *fileSizeNumber = [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize];
 long long fileSize = [fileSizeNumber longLongValue];
 NSLog(@"%lld",fileSize);

 float sizeKB = ((float)fileSize / 1000);
 NSLog(@"%f",sizeKB);

 float sizeMB = ((float)fileSize / 1000000);
 NSLog(@"%f",sizeMB);

 if (sizeMB >= 100.0)
 {
     [arrList addObject:file];
     [test addObject:file.lastPathComponent];
 }
```

Hope it helps someone else also.