# How to get the sizes of all files in mac in objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nsfilemanager

I am having a cocoa mac app for OSX.

In my app, I want to get the sizes of all the files in my mac programmatically in objective c.

Here is the [image]

I have searched a lot but unable to find proper solution.

I am finding the system size with the following code.

```
NSError *error;

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [fileManager attributesOfFileSystemForPath:@"/" error:&error];
```

But how to get the size of all files in mac programmatically.

Please guide me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Please help me.

Comment: You realize that there is easily a million files on your Mac, and possibly more?

Comment: I have seen a mac app which finds the size of files having a size above 100Mb. I also want to get the list like that. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

See [File Attribute Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/File_Attribute_Keys).

> `NSFileSize`
>
> The key in a file attribute dictionary whose value indicates the file's size in bytes.
>
> The corresponding value is an `NSNumber` object containing an `unsigned long long`.

```
unsigned long long fileSize = [fileAttributes[NSFileSize] unsignedLongLongValue];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply again. Can you please give me the exact code for this? I want to get the list of all files with their sizes and paths.

Comment: @Manthan Ah you want the size of all files in the filesystem.  I cannot be bothered to look at that as it sounds like it will take too long.

Comment: There's no way to ask "please give me a cascading list of every file in the system that I have permission to know about, with their sizes" because (i) basically nobody wants that information; and (ii) that information isn't stored anywhere in that form. Download something like GrandPerspective and check out how long it takes to run if set to scan a whole disk. That's because it has to walk all the folders, querying the information.

Comment: Ok buy I don't understand what is wrong in that and people downvote.

Comment: @Tommy: Basically I want to get the list of files with sizes above 100 MB.

Comment: In that case, read the Spotlight documentation. Don't ask me to do it for you and explain it to you, read it yourself.

Comment: And if you want a list of all files with sizes above 100 MB, why do you ask a question about getting the sizes of all files, which obviously has a totally different answer?

Comment: I asked a general question to get the list of files. Yes, that might be not a good one but you should have corrected for that. If you don't want to answer then its also fine.

Comment: I got my answer... Thanks @Droppy for your suggetions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31308695/get-the-list-of-files-from-selected-folders-having-sizes-100mb-with-their-paths.